# Collecting select values into an array (jQuery)

Tags: html, jquery

I've been attempting to collect the selected data value of each of the dropdowns in a form and pass them into an array so that I can eventually add them together. However with my current code, the array only receives the value of the first dropdown, and not any of the others. I haven't got to the addition part yet, so I'm just joining the array with a comma, but here's my code so far:

**HTML**

```
 <form id="questions">
    <select name="q1" id="q1" tabindex="1">
        <option data-calculate="0" value="No">No</option>
        <option data-calculate="0.5" value="Partially">Partially</option>
        <option data-calculate="1" value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
    <select name="q2" id="q2" tabindex="2">
        <option data-calculate="0" value="No">No</option>
        <option data-calculate="0.5" value="Partially">Partially</option>
        <option data-calculate="1" value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
    <select name="q3" id="q3" tabindex="3">
        <option data-calculate="0" value="No">No</option>
        <option data-calculate="0.5" value="Partially">Partially</option>
        <option data-calculate="1" value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="calculator" value=""/>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var calculation = [];

jQuery("#questions").change(function() {
    calculation.push(jQuery(this).find(":selected").data('calculate'));
    jQuery("#calculator").val(calculation.join(', '));
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: In your change event, `this` will be the `form` as that's where you've attached the event.   If you did `$("#questions select").change(..` then `this` would be the `select`.

Comment: However, you'd then have the issue that *every* time you change a value, it will add to the calculation array.  Instead, on the change event just recalculate from all `select`s instead of keeping a "running total".   `var tot = $("select :selected").map(o=>$(o).data("calculate") * 1).toArray().reduce((pv,cv) => pv+cv)` (or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#questions > select").change(function(event) {
    var calc = [];
    $("#questions > select").each(function(i, el) {
      calc.push($(el).val());
    });
    $("#calculator").val(calc.join(", "));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="questions">
  <select name="q1" id="q1" tabindex="1">
    <option data-calculate="0" value="No">No</option>
    <option data-calculate="0.5" value="Partially">Partially</option>
    <option data-calculate="1" value="Yes">Yes</option>
  </select>
  <select name="q2" id="q2" tabindex="2">
    <option data-calculate="0" value="No">No</option>
    <option data-calculate="0.5" value="Partially">Partially</option>
    <option data-calculate="1" value="Yes">Yes</option>
  </select>
  <select name="q3" id="q3" tabindex="3">
    <option data-calculate="0" value="No">No</option>
    <option data-calculate="0.5" value="Partially">Partially</option>
    <option data-calculate="1" value="Yes">Yes</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="calculator" value="" />
</form>
```

Each change to a `select` element triggers the callback. Making a more global variable will cause it to get updated over and over again if the User makes many changes or changes their selection. This will capture all 3 values and join them. If the user changes a selection, the hidden field is updated with just the values currently selected.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I've give it a try.